# C Arrays gives address instead of value when second array is created

Tags: c, arrays

First of all, sorry for my English. I hope you will still understand what my problem is.

I am new to C programming and I am a bit confused. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tableaux.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

 int tableauUn[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};

 printf("%d\n", sommeTableau(tableauUn, 4));
 printf("%d\n", moyenneTableau(tableauUn, 4));

 return 0;

}
```

And this is the file where my functions are. I also have a file where I have my prototypes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tableaux.h" 

int sommeTableau(int tableau[], int taille) {
    int resultat;

    for (int i = 0; i < taille; i++) {
        resultat += tableau[i];
    }
    return resultat;
}

int moyenneTableau(int tableau[], int taille) {
    int resultat;

    for (int i = 0; i < taille; i++) {
        resultat += tableau[i];
    }

    return resultat / taille;
}

void copierTableau(int tableau[], int taille, int tableauDeux[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < taille; i++) {
        tableauDeux[i] = tableau[i];
    }
}
```

So everything works fine. The first printf gives me the total of the values that are stored in the array and the second one gives me the average of the values.

```
5
1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

What I don't understand is why do I get this result when I want to create a second array ?

```
int tableauUn[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
int tableauDeux[4] = {0};
```

the result

```
1606416356
1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

So I haven't used the second array but the result of the first printf changes and I am a bit confused with what is going on.

I hope you can help me !

Comment: `int resultat;` should be `int resultat = 0;` in both `sommeTableau` and `moyenneTableau`.  It was always wrong; you just got lucky the first time.

Comment: @user3121023  Oh I see. Thank you so much !

Comment: @zwol Thanks to you as well. That makes sense !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please initialize the sum you return in function

```
int resultat = 0;
```

otherwise resultat will take garbage value as initial value

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about that. Thank you!